# PostgreSQL query to return free rooms for booking availability calender

Tags: postgresql

I need bit of a help in writing an SQL query.
A simple scenario is that I have a table named `BookedRooms` in which three columns are used most, `checkInDate` and `checkOutDate`, both are of type timestamp and `roomId` which is a `foreign key` to the `Rooms` table.
Now Rooms table has PK,  `name` column and `roomNo` column.

This is `BookedRooms` table

```
+----+----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--+
| PK |          checkInDate       |            checkOutDate |           roomId |  |
+----+----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--+
|  1 |     2022-05-26T00:00:00Z   |   2022-05-29T00:00:00Z  |                2 |  |
|  2 |     2022-05-29T00:00:00Z   |   2022-05-30T00:00:00Z  |                3 |  |
+----+----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--+
```

This is `Rooms` table

```
+----+------------+-------------------+--+
| PK |      name  |            roomNo |  |
+----+------------+-------------------+--+
|  2 |     Deluxe |               102 |  |
|  3 |       King |               103 |  |
+----+------------+-------------------+--+
```

Now, i wanna write a query in which if i put the month number like `4` , it tells me `name` and `roomNo` of Rooms which are free for each particular day of the month.

The logic to check if a room is occupied is that, if for example room `102` has a `checkin` date of `03` of month `April` and `checkout` date of `06` of `month` April , then the query will not include this room in the result set until the `checkout` date has come, only for that date and onwards would it include room `102` in the result set, again until this room appears in another `checkInDate` column somewhere.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating an exclusion constraint on `bookedrooms`. Not only can the GiST index that implements the constraint speed up the search you want, but it will also exclude double booking.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

ALTER TABLE bookedrooms ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
   tstzrange(checkindate, checkoutdate) WITH &&,
   roomid WITH =
);
```

The query you need is

```
SELECT roomno FROM bookedrooms
EXCEPT
SELECT roomno FROM bookedrooms
WHERE tstzrange(checkindate, checkoutdate) &&
      tstzrange(
         date_trunc('year', current_timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 month' * 4,
         date_trunc('year', current_timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 month' * (4 + 1)
      );
```

`&&` is the "overlaps" operator for ranges.

Comment: Getting this error `function tsrange(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`

Comment: Then you have to use `tstzrange`. I guessed `timestamp`, since you said so in your question.